# Connectedness of boundary of a 'cluster' of open domains

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $F:=\{U_j\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d\}_j$ be a countable disjoint collection of bounded open connected sets whose complement $U_j^c$ is connected as well (recall that this [implies](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265812109_On_the_connectedness_of_boundary_and_complement_for_domains) that $\partial U_j$ is connected). We say that $F$ 'clusters together' in the sense that $X:=\overline{\bigcup_{j}U_j}$ is assumed to be connected. Is $X\setminus \left(\bigcup_{j}U_j\right)$ connected then?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A,B\subseteq \underbrace{X\setminus \left(\bigcup_{U\in F}U\right)}_{=:\partial}$ are non-empty disjoint clopen sets s.t. $A \cup B = \partial$. It is straightforward to construct disjoint open sets ${\cal A},\,{\cal B}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ s.t. $A={\cal A}\cap \partial$ and $B={\cal B}\cap \partial$ and
$${\cal A}\cap \left(\bigcup_{j:\,\partial U_j\subseteq B}\overline{U_j}\right)=\emptyset={\cal B}\cap \left(\bigcup_{j:\,\partial U_j\subseteq A}\overline{U_j}\right).$$ The sets
$$C:={\cal A}\cup\left(\bigcup_{j:\,\partial U_j\subseteq A}U_j\right),\qquad D:={\cal B}\cup\left(\bigcup_{j:\,\partial U_j\subseteq B}U_j\right)$$
are open and non-intersecting. Moreover, we have that $X\subseteq C\cup D$ while $X\cap C$ and $X\cap D$ define non-empty disjoint clopen sets (in the induced topology on $X$), contradicting the connectedness of $X$.